# How to wrap instance and class methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I would like to add to class `D` some common functionality that composed of instance methods and class methods. I tried to do this like below, but it didn't work. What is the right way to achieve this ?

```
module A
  def foo
    puts "foo!"
  end
end

module B
  def wow
    puts "wow!"
  end
end

module C
  include A   # instance methods
  extend B    # class methods
end

class D
  include C
end

D.new.foo
D.wow
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to define C like this to be able to do what you want:

```
module C
  include A

  def self.included( base )
    base.extend B #"base" here is "D"
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the meaning of `self` here ? What if I omit it ?

Comment: self makes included a "module method" .. similar to a "class method"  It will not work if you remove it.

Comment: @Misha If you omit it, it will break. `def self.xxx` defines a method on the class/module itself rather than as a method to be inherited by instances.